# Secretary Management of Calendar:- Specific Requirements

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

I have a user who says that they had the following functionality in outlook which has stopped working after a profile rebuild.  Reviewing the permissions I cant find an option on how to get this specific functionality.

- Exchange 2010 (Up to date SBS 2011)
- Outlook 2013 (There are some other users using outlook 2010)

Secretary schedules appointments for manager and another party.  The manager must then approve the appointment and will receive the response from the other party.

The secretary has no further interaction and does not receive updates on the meeting.

If someone could advise on this it would be appreciated on if this is possible and if so what settings/permissions would need to be applied.

Comment: Isn't this just the secretary being set as a delegate for the manager's account?

Comment: What we are finding is that using delegation the user can setup appointments for the manager but they are automatically accepted in the managers calendar rather than then being approved by the manager.